# how to pass object to a controller inside success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).on("keyup.autocomplete", "#idkey", function(){ 
var query = "q=" + $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: query,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            content = data[i].IDKey;
            content += "<br>";
            $(content).appendTo("#output");
            // updateListing(data[x]);
        }
    }
});
});
```

how to pass this data object to a controller using url or any other method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: you can use ajax again to send object to your controller

Comment: thanks for the comment that was helpfull